# javascript to add aria attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, wai-aria

I'm trying to add aria-required="true" attributes to some form elements from ninja forms in wordpress. I'm using a header/footer script inject plugin. But I can't seem to get my code to actually work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://champion.magnet.today/contact/

```js
<script>
function codeAddress() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("nf-element");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addAttribute("aria-required", "true");
    }
window.onload = codeAddress
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="nf-field-element">
    <input id="nf-field-17" name="nf-field-17" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [**setAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Also window.load should be outside the `codeAddress` function

```js
function codeAddress() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("nf-element");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i])
    x[i].setAttribute("aria-required", "true");
  }

}
window.onload = codeAddress
```

```html
<div class="nf-field-element">
  <input id="nf-field-17" name="nf-field-17" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried that, still no luck. I'm not sure if it's because the form elements are being generated via the ninja forms plugin. I tested it by using a button to run it and it seems to works. Is there a method to get it to just work on the entire page without a function?

Comment: Probably not the best method but I've used a delay and it seems to work fine now. 

setTimeout (function() {codeAddress();}, 2000);

Answer (score 1):

try replacing `x[i].addAttribute("aria-required", "true");` with `x[i].setAttribute("aria-required", "true");`